# Balanced Brackets example

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

So i am trying to Balance the sequence of brackets.
For more info refer: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/balanced-brackets/problem?isFullScreen=true
I want to use numpy arrays instead of using lists. Now the problem that I am facing is I don't know how to pop out the elements from the np array and store it in another list/array as there is no pop() function in numpy. Kindly help me here.
Here is the code. Reply me with the solution code too.

```
import numpy as np
t = int(input("Count: "))
while t:
    ar = np.array('')
    s = input()
    for i in s:
        if i == '(':
            np.append(['('])
        elif i == '[':
            np.append(['['])
        elif i == '{':
            np.append(['{'])
        elif i == ')':
            k = np.pop(ar)
            if k != '(':
                np.append(['k'])
                break
        elif i == ']':
            k = np.pop(ar)
            if k != '[':
                np.append(['k'])
                break
        elif i == '}':
            k = np.pop(ar)
            if k != '{':
                np.append(['k'])
                break
        
    if len(ar) == 0 or ar[len(ar)-1] != '':
        print('NO')
    else:
        print('YES')
    t-=1
```

I tried inserting the string of brackets in array but now i dont know how to pop them out and store it in another array

Comment: Why numpy array for this?

Comment: you can use, `np.delete(array, index)`. But I have the same question too, why are you using numpy array for this?

Comment: Don't use numpy with loops, this will be slower than pure python.

Comment: To be a bit more concrete than the other comments: Numpy arrays are really good if you want to do common operations on the individual elements and if you want to do stuff like paste together entire arrays into larger arrays, especially if you are using numbers. Numpy array with strings are not something you probably want to be using, and taking away elements from a numpy array is also something you should be avoiding.

Comment: `np.append` is not a clone of the list append. You forgot to even look at its docs.

Answer (score 0):

Mapping closing and opening brackets using a `dict` would make it much simpler and cleaner. Also, `numpy` is not helpful for this case. A simple solution would be:

```
def isBalanced(s):
    data = {')':'(','}':'{',']':'['}
    lst=[]

    # Loop through each character.
    for char in s:
        # if it is opening
        if char in data.values():
            lst.append(char)

        elif lst:
            # if closing doesn't pair up with opening
            if not data[char] == lst.pop():
                return "NO"

        else:
            # if unwanted character is passsed
            return "NO"

    # if all the brackets are closed in order
    return "NO" if lst else "YES"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over-complicating this. You definitely don't want or need numpy. Just a straightforward Python list will suffice.

Something like this:

```
def isBalanced(s):
    stack = []
    left = set('({[')
    rmap = {
        ')': '(',
        '}': '{',
        ']': '['
    }
    for c in s:
        if c in left:
            stack.append(c)
        else:
            if not stack or stack.pop() != rmap.get(c):
                return 'NO'
    return 'NO' if stack else 'YES'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very simple recursive approach:

```
def is_matched(my_string):
    right = {'(': ')', '[': ']', '{': '}'}
    if not my_string:
        return True
    if my_string[-1] == right[my_string[0]]:
        return is_matched(my_string[1:-1])
    return False
```